# Database design's performance: One database for n customers vs a database per customer

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design

Consider a web application project with MySQL database which supposed to serve multiple companies. These companies are completely unrelated and thus should not have access to each other's data. There are two designs I can think of to implement such an application:

**1. Using a `company_id` for tables to indicate the owner of each record.** This way one database will be shared among multiple companies.

**2. Dedicating a database to each company.** This way the `company_id` field will be omitted and data isolation provides better security assurance. Yet multiple companies will share a MySQL instance (it's not possible to dedicate a MySQL instance to each company due to profit aspects of the project).

If we assume that both approaches are feasible (security-wise) **which one is more performant?**

I believe it all comes down to overhead of having a database in MySQL but I'm not sure how much is that!

Answer (score 1):

From a performance perspective the differences are absolutely negligible.

Having `company_id` in every table adds a bit of a programming load to every form, etc., but is THE standard way to do it. This would be considered "best practice".

Having a separate database for each company allows an administrator to be appointed from the company and they can do, for instance, backups or truncates without fear of seeing or deleting someone else's data. This, IMO, would be the only reason to go with multiple databases.

Comment: What about the saved memory (and CPU) due to omitting the `company_id` index? Mostly I'm interested in a comparison between the cost of `company_id` index and having a separate database.

Comment: I think the overhead of having multiple databases would roughly equate to the memory/CPU of the company_id index.  Really I think the word "negligible" is the right answer. Unless you have relatively strong business reasons, go with the company_id column and a single database.

Comment: If their difference is negligible I would rather take the second approach because of its simplicity and improved security.

Comment: I'm not sure re the improved security - I don't really see that.  Being able to add a new company from the application itself without accessing the dB, not having multiple tables that need to be updated when (not if) a change is made, etc are all reasons why 1 db is better than multiple. There's a reason why that would be "best practice." But it is your choice - it's no skin off my nose...

Comment: Security depends a lot on how your clients work.  I hope you do not let individual companies connect directly to MySQL.  Rather I hope that there is some API layer in between.  If so, then that is where the "security" should be.